# Load html string that contains javascript with src from assets

Tags: android, webview, android-webview

I want to load this html to webview. But it does not understand compatibility.js, customview.js, pdf.js in the assets folder.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="minimal.css"/>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/compatibility.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var url = '/storage/sdcard/Download/test.pdf';
    </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <button id="prev" onclick="goPrevious()" class="button">Previous</button>
    <button id="next" onclick="goNext()" class="button">Next</button>
    &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <span>Page: <span id="page_num"></span> / <span id="page_count"></span></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <canvas id="the-canvas" style="border:1px solid black"></canvas>
  </div>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/pdf.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///android_asset/customview.js"></script>  
</body>
</html>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Oh my html works after change from

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html_string, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

to

```
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/", html_string, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but if your stylesheet is loaded correctly,
use the same approach for js files.
Meaning put the js files in the same folder and do not specify the file protocol.
If that is working for you you can
try to put js files back in the asset folder and Declare the correct relative path.